# iOS Significant location changes is available during roaming?

Tags: ios, cellular-network, roaming

Does anyone knows if the **significant location changes** service works properly when the phone is  roaming or there are restrictions? In the offical doc I don't find any useful info.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are location changes updated when the ios devices are roaming.

You can use delegate method of MKMapView to see the location changes as the device roams.
More information can be found on: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

Comment: I'm not sure it concern. I'm interest only to 'Significant location changes service', which use only cellular data. MKMapView instead get info from GPS hardware.

Comment: As per apple.- Gathering location data is a power-intensive operation. It involves powering up the onboard radios and querying the available cell towers, Wi-Fi hotspots, or GPS satellites, which can take several seconds. Leaving the standard location service running for extended periods can drain the device’s battery. (The significant-change location service drastically reduces battery drain by monitoring only cell tower changes, but the service works only on devices with cellular radios.) For most apps, it is usually sufficient to establish an initial position fix and then acquire updates onl

Comment: You continue talking about GPS services, my request instead is about "Significant location changes service" which is completely different.

Comment: The Answer to your questions is YES location changes are updated when your device is roaming but the level of accuracy is not much as The GPS service and it might be slower then the GPS but it is low power consumption method it does not drain your battery the way GPS does